# Transition from discrete case to a continuous case with regards to the Born's Rule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, probability, born-rule

I learned that given that the eigenvalue equation is $$
\widehat{A}\left|u_{n}^{i}\right\rangle=\lambda_{n}\left|u_{n}^{i}\right\rangle
$$
where $
i \in\{1,2, \ldots, g_n\}
$, and that the state $
|\psi\rangle
$ is not normalised, the probability of obtaining an eigenvalue $
\lambda_{n}
$ is given by:
$$
P\left(\lambda_{n}\right)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{g_{n}}\left|\left\langle u_{i}^{n} \mid \psi\right\rangle\right|^{2}}{\langle\psi \mid \psi\rangle}
$$
Now, from a discrete case, if we shift to the case with a continuous eigenvalue equation given by:
$$
\hat{A}\left|v_{\alpha}\right\rangle=\alpha\left|v_{\alpha}\right\rangle
$$
where $\alpha$ is a continuous variable, then how can we naturally move on from the above probability expression to its continuous case wherein we happen to bring in the concept of probability density?

I tried to tackle this by first writing down an arbitrary ket in the state space as:
$$
|\psi\rangle=\int  c(\alpha)\left|v_{\alpha}\right\rangle d \alpha
$$
where $c(\alpha)=\left\langle v_{\alpha} \mid \psi\right\rangle$ which is the wavefunction here.

Is it correct to use the same analogy for the discrete case and write down the probability of measuring an eigenvalue as given below?
$$
P(\alpha)=|c(\alpha) d \alpha|^{2}
$$
I somehow need to come to the result:
$$
\frac{d P(\alpha)}{d \alpha}=\frac{|c(\alpha)|^{2}}{\langle\psi \mid \psi\rangle}
$$

Any idea or a complete result will be appreciated. I just want a smooth transition from discrete case to a continuous case.

Comment: A proper answer to this question requires some non trivial functional analysis and treatment of infinite dimensional linear spaces. To start, if $\alpha$ belongs to the continuum spectrum then it has no eigenvector. In any case the Born rule (which is what you are after) can be written with projectors in a way which is valid for all cases.

Comment: @lcv, if possible, could you answer this question using the non-trivial functional analysis you are referring to? It would be very helpful.

Comment: I can try to give it a go when I find some time.

Comment: related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98455/conceptual-difficulty-in-understanding-continuous-vector-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly on the right track.
I will give a simple explanation without any mathematical rigour.

When the system is in state
$$|\psi\rangle = \int c(\alpha)|v_\alpha\rangle d\alpha$$
then, when measuring $\hat{A}$, the probability of
obtaining a value in the range $[\alpha, \alpha + d\alpha]$ is
$$dP(\alpha) = \frac{|c(\alpha)|^2 d\alpha}{\langle\psi|\psi\rangle}.$$
Note that the probability $dP(\alpha)$ needs to be a differential
(when $d\alpha\to 0$ you also have $dP(\alpha)\to 0$).
Therefore it is an equation between infinitesimal quantities.
Dividing this equation by $d\alpha$ you get a probability density
$$\frac{dP(\alpha)}{d\alpha} = \frac{|c(\alpha)|^2}{\langle\psi|\psi\rangle}.$$

Comment: I wanted a more rigorous explanation, but I think this explanation works intuitively for me.